# ¿Se puede validar un checkbox con errorprovider?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo 2 checkboxes uno para seleccionar "SI" y otro para seleccionar "NO", he validado algunos controles como textbox o combobox con el control ErrorProvider, me pregunto si esa validacion se puede hacer con un checkbox para que aparezca el simbolo de error a lado del control, lo que quiero es evitar los MessageBox para que sea mas amigable.

Comment: ¿Los dos checkbox son excluyentes?

Comment: Son excluentes, agregue la propiedad RadioGroupIndex en ambos checkboxs para que funcionaran como RadioButton.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que se puede, pero para el caso que usted plantea debe usar un control `RadioButton` si solo tendrá dos opciones y solo se requiere una al mismo tiempo.

Pero aqui tiene un ejemplo de validación con `CheckBox`:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
     errorProvider1.SetError(checkBox1, "Requiere Selección.");
else
    errorProvider1.Clear();
```